# LTSpice coupling inductors across subcircuits

Tags: pspice

I have two subcircuits that each contain an inductor. Specifying inductive coupling between two inductors on the main level is easily done, but how do I do it, if the inductors are hidden in the subcircuits? How do I reference those inductors?
Sorry, there was no LTSpice tag, so I used PSpice, I hope the answer is similar.